# Local Source control repository - cross platform

Tags: version-control, cross-platform, development-environment

I am looking for a 'local' source control software, I don't need it to be necessarily available on network.. Its meant to be only for personal use..
What I am looking for is something like:

Need it to be cross platform. The biggest problem is, I need the same local repository to be available on both windows and Linux! (Is this even possible? :s ) I dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu and have managed to setup workspace that works in both OS without changes, now I need a source control software!

Easy installation, I have never installed one before! :)

And Has eclipse plugin..

I have used VSS for this purpose before, but that is only on Windows!
I looked for Mercurial, but I am not sure if I can use the same repository on both the OS!
Any suggestions are appreciated!

UPDATE: Thanks for your replies.. Yes I do want the same repository to be accessed from different operating systems.. Everyone has suggested an on-line repository but I 'need it to be local'.. Internet is not something I can depend on (I now know git takes care of this..! :)), I would not want version of, say my personal recordings of some home functions tweaked in audacity, to be hosted on-line! Right now, I am trying out git, as a local repository solution..

Comment: @May, Local means file system access, even if it is over network. If you want to access it from several machines any kind of source control will do, as long you are hosting the server.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can Mercurial, since the whole repository is in .hg folder.
 Try [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) - it's easy to install and use.

Answer (score 2):

If you definitely want a repository that's always available on a local filesystem, I'd probably go for Mercurial or Git.  Most likely Mercurial, as it has the best windows support (including the TortoiseHg gui), but Git works similarly.

But there's two other issues:

1. Do you make frequent backups?
2. What file system type will you use for the shared repository?

In this particular case, I would not trust a single shared filesystem as the best basket to put your eggs in; In each boot environment, I would maintain working repositories separate from the shared one.  This would give you some redundancy.

Here's how this would work:

Two repositories U and W, for Ubuntu and Windows respectively, and one shared repository S, accessable frome either boot environment.

Assuming a stable situation, with all three repositories in sync:

1. Commit any new code to repository U in Ubuntu.

   `$ hg commit -m 'changes from linux'`
2. Push the changes to S.

   `$ hg push`
3. Reboot into windows.

   ...
4. Pull the latest changesets from S into W

   `W> hg fetch`
5. Update your code, commit frequently
6. Push prior to rebooting into linux

   `W> hg push`
7. Reboot
8. And repeat step 4, but now from linux

   `$ hg fetch`       # performs an hg pull, followed by an update.
9. Rinse, lather, repeat.

That's said, with both Mercurial *and* Git, you can synchronise your repositories across the net any time, so I would surely recommend you try that out some time.

And note: the best backup is having a copy of your data on a live file system on another computer, preferably at another location.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want it to be local? The benefit of source control, is that you can have multiple clients working on the same source, without worrying too much about conflicts etc.

Even though it doesn't really answer your question, this advices might solve your problem:
Just create a project for yourself at https://github.com/ or http://sourceforge.net/ any other free online repository hosting provider. SVN, CVS, GIT all come with excellent IDE integration and clients run on almost all operating systems.

Hope this helps. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to have a duplicate repository on different operating systems?  That doesn't make sense to me. What would be the purpose of doing that?

I think you instead want to have a single repository that you can access from any operating system.

In this case, you can just install Subversion (or whatever source control system you prefer) on a server and access it from the operating systems you use.  There are plenty of client tools for Mac/Windows/Linux that can talk to subversion repositories, RapidSVN being free and cross-platform for one.

If you don't have your own server, there are plenty of places online that will host Subversion for you.

Comment: With a dvcs like `hg` or `git` you can have as many clones of your repository as you like, in fact from a redundancy point of view, the more the merrier. With an `svn` repo, you'd better keep pretty good backups, since it's a single point of failure, but with a dvcs any of the local clones can be used to re-populate the shared repo if it ever gets corrupted.